# Swift 2: Specifying required variables in an abstract superclass

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write something that  a class and a protocol. I just want a sort of protocol with explicitly defined functions or.

```
protocol ObjectProtocol {
    var endpoint: String
}

class Object {
    // All subclasses must implement ObjectProtocol

    func printAPIEndpoint() { print(endpoint) }
}
```

so that I can easily define classes like this:

```
class User: Object, ObjectProtocol {
    var endpoint = "localhost:3000"
}
```

What's the best way to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A protocol extension with a default method implementation
 might be what you are looking for:

```
protocol ObjectProtocol {
    var endpoint: String { get }
}

extension ObjectProtocol {
    func printAPIEndpoint() { print(endpoint) }
}
```

This defines a default method `printAPIEndpoint()` for all
types conforming to `ObjectProtocol`, compare
"Providing Default Implementations" in ["Protocols"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) in the Swift reference.

Example usage:

```
class User: ObjectProtocol {
    var endpoint = "localhost:3000"
}

let user = User()
user.printAPIEndpoint()
```